# php -v command in command prompt not working on windows

Tags: php

I have downloaded the php v 7.3 from https://www.php.net/releases/
after downloading and extracting I have added the path to my envirnoment variables.
but after restarting command prompt and executing `php -v` i cant see the php version.
what I found issue is that there is no php.exe file inside the folder, can you tell me where is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page you linked to is offering the *source code* for different versions of PHP; to use them, you would need to compile them for your platform.

If you are looking for Windows binaries, you need to look at https://windows.php.net/ which explains the different options available for currently supported versions. (It also has links to instructions for building from source, if you want to attempt that.)

However, [PHP 7.3 is no longer supported](https://www.php.net/eol.php), so if you really need that version for some reason, you will need to find an appropriate download in the [release archive page](https://windows.php.net/downloads/releases/archives/). It would obviously be generally preferable to use [a version which is still actively supported](https://www.php.net/supported-versions), but I realise there are sometimes reasons it's not as simple as that.

Comment: He would also add manually **PHP** to `path` environment variable

Comment: @medilies a) the question says they already did that; and b) adding to the path makes no difference if you haven't actually downloaded or compiled an executable.